# C# customstructure=double

Tags: c#

I know it's simple, but I don't know what should I search for. I want to have a custom structure that would have some additional functionality to double. But as I found out, it's impossible to inherit from double. How do I make such a structure? Here is a sample how I'd like to use it:

```
GradeValue val=1.5;
string stringRepresentation=val.ToString();//returns "1-"
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `GradeValue`?

Comment: That's what I want to ask. It can be struct or class, I don't care.

Comment: What is the logic for getting from the value `1.5` to the string representation `"1-"`?

Comment: Wrap a `double`, and define operators/constructors for conversion to/from `double`.

Comment: What is your 'additional functionality'?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public struct GradeValue // : IComparable, IFormattable, ...
{
    private readonly double m_value;
    private GradeValue(double value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator GradeValue(double value)
    {
        return new GradeValue(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator double(GradeValue c)
    {
        return c.m_value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // ToDo: What is the logic???
        return "1-";
    }
}
```

This is just a base for the further extension if you need additional operators, comparisons, etc...

Comment: Thank you, sorry for terribly specifying the problem. This is exactly what I needed. The logic: it's a school grade (European). It bascialy changes x.5 to x-. So 2.5 is 2-, 3.5 is 3- etc.

Comment: Wow, a-ha! I am from Serbia and we have the same system, but did not ring a bell when I saw it first.

Comment: You should be able to do that with an enum (and a DescriptionAttribute).

Comment: If he does not need an actual grade value like `3.67` then it is surely better to use `enum`

Comment: @czubehead - shouldn't `1.5` equate to `"1-2"`; and `"1-"` would be `1.25`? -- and `1.75` would be `"2+"`?

Comment: @Corak Yes, it should, but teachers can't write it, they can write whole or "minus" grades only.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that. `double` is a very special type, along with the other primitive numbers and `IntPtr`.

However there are some things you *can* do:

- You can make a `GradeValue` struct/class with implicit conversion operators to/from `double` (or maybe a `decimal` would be more appropriate here?)
- You can make extension methods for `double` that do all the grade-specific logic.

Comment: I must say my mouse already hovered on the downvote button when I've read *"I don't think you can do that."* :-)